# Wildcard dynamic subdomain(s) in Homestead Laravel 5.1 on OS X Yosemite

Tags: laravel, nginx, dns, subdomain, homestead

I'm trying to get wildcard subdomains to resolve locally on my mac (OS X Yosemite).

A user creates their own site and based on their username they will have username.project.mac (or *.project.mac).

I have Homestead working correctly for `www.project.mac`, `app.project.mac` and `project.mac` as these are pre-set routes, but I need `username.project.mac` to be dynamic.

.hosts

```
# Homestead
192.168.10.10 project.mac
192.168.10.10 app.project.mac
192.168.10.10 www.project.mac
```

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: project.mac
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/project/user.project.com/public
    - map: app.project.mac
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/project/app.project.com/public
    - map: www.project.mac
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/project/www.project.com/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{username}.project.mac'], function ($username) {
    return $username;
});
```

I have even been through this tutorial: http://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/ which 'seems' to have worked until the very last point where I can't resolve `test.testing.mac` when I try to ping it. `project.mac` does resolve when I ping it.

I have also edited `/etc/nginx/sites-available/project.mac` to `server_name project.mac *.project.mac;` as per this reply: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/homestead-and-subdomains/replies/46620

I have no idea what else to try.

Comment: I have the same queston..

Comment: I got it working from this thread: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/wildcard-dynamic-subdomains-in-homestead-laravel-51-on-os-x-yosemite - Let me know it you get stuck

Comment: You may have to edit the .htaccess file....

Answer (score 0):

First problem identitied
Usually wildcard domains may not work as *.domain.com. But you may have to try

```
server_name ~^(.*)\.example\.com$ example.com ;
```

Even if you add make changes in /etc/nginx/sites-available/project.mac make sure a symlink of this is available in sites-enabled directory as well. Unless symlink is present in sites-enabled directory your changes on prokect.mac file wont reflect.

go to sites-enabled directory and

```
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/project.mac
```

you may need to reload nginx server configs using

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```